# can I login in skype with skype api?

Tags: java, api, skype

currently m working on a project,i searched through the internet for 12 hours but no success.
I simply have a question that can i login in Skype with Skype API??If yes,please mention which is that.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://www.skype.com/en/developer/?

Comment: I found nothing helpful there.

Comment: I also tried, searches Skype developer docs as well but not success.